# using titles in maps API

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

I am having a hard time passing a variable to the Google Maps API

I'm trying to create markers with custom titles based on what's inside the following array

```
var addresses = [{"atitle":"ROUTE 114 LIQUORS","street":"175 ANDOVER STREET+01960 "},{"atitle":"DOWNTOWN WINE &amp; SPIRITS","street":"225 ELM STREET (DAVIS SQU+02143 "},{"atitle":"WEGMANS-NORTHBOROUGH","street":"9102 SHOPS WAY+01532 "},{"atitle":"POWERS LIQUORS","street":"23 WOOD STREET+01851 "}];

var x;

for ( x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) { 

 var reTitle = addresses[x].atitle;
 reTitle = reTitle.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function (m, n) { return String.fromCharCode(n); });
 alert(reTitle);//this works fine.

    jQuery.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x].street+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
        var aTitle = reTitle;
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: aTitle
        });

    });

}
```

Markers are fine. Title won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery.getJSON is asynchronous.  After the loop completes, `x = addresses.length` (not a valid entry for the addresses array).  At that point all the callback functions execute and addresses[x].title is undefined.

This issue is typically solved with function closure.